# Background image on Phonegap causes incredible slowness?

Tags: css, cordova, background-image

So after much frustration, I finally pin-pointed the problem. The following causes severe decline in speed in my phonegap app:

```
body.default {
    background: #000000 url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image was 1500 x 1500 pixels and about 350Kb. I optimized it a bit and decreased the dimensions to 1000 x 1000. This resulted in a final size of 106Kb.

The problem is, even when I make it smaller like this, it still slows down the app considerably. However if I have this:

```
body.default {
    background: none;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then the speed is nice and fast. So I know the background is causing the slowness.

What can I do to still show a good quality as the background, without killing performance?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get an "ok" result if I decrease the image size to 36 kb. Of course, then I loose a lot of the quality, but it has an overlay, so it's not that noticeable. However, I think that it might be background-size: cover, that might be inefficient, but I haven't tested that yet. I will keep trying...

Comment: How do you defined "incredible slowness"? Open your network tab in developer console and check the timeline for the image... it should show various times, such as Request Sent, Time to First Byte, and Content Download. If the TTFB/Request Sent are in much greater proportion to the content download time, then it may be a server issue. A 36kb image is pretty small. Also, are you enabling gzipping on your server?

Comment: It's fine on my Browser, it just gets very slow on my Sony M2. If I take the background away, it's blazing fast. So I need to find a way to make it work better with a background image. I noticed that making it smaller helps a bit, but I feel like I'm missing something. I don't understand why a 36Kb background image that covers a div, would cause my phone to slow down so much. When I click on a button, it takes almost 3 seconds to get to the next screen.

Comment: Okay, I know I keep going back to the network tab thing, but humor me here... You should be able to do `chrome://inspect` in your browser while your phone is plugged in to inspect what's happening on your phone (I'm not worried about the browser here). Cordova is essentially just a native webview wrapped around some html/css/js.

Comment: Right, so I dont have it set up like that. I use build.phonegap.com to build the app, and then I install it on my phone to test. You would be my hero if you don't mind explaining what you mean so I can report back? Must I use the phonegap app?

Comment: PhoneGap/Cordova (whatever you want to call it) is inherently finnicky. I'm just interested to see what's going on with transport, etc. It would be a lot easier to discover the root of the problem if we could see what's happening in the console.

Comment: If you're installing and testing it on your phone, you should still be able to plug the phone into your computer, open the app, and then in Chrome on your computer, go to `chrome://inspect`

Comment: I may be completely wrong, and I know you've tested with vs without the background image and noticed the slowness only when the background image is there, but being only 36kb, I am skeptical that that is truly the issue.

Comment: @JoshBeam, i agree! I am sort of waiting for someone to reply with suggestions, but I think I just got one myself. The background has an overlay, and that could perhaps be a factor too. I'm going to update the question with more info after I do a few more tests.

Comment: And I will try the inspect thing too!